# Best way to use a custom field with Datatransformer in a Symfony2 page

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a custom field type 'customnum', having a DataTransformer. Everything works fine in a form, when given to the Builder like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('number','customnum')
        ->add('active')
```

How can i use the custom field (the DataTransformer) starting with a typical indexAction page, build by doctrines CRUD?

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entities = $em->getRepository('TwarSoz3Bundle:Organization')->findAll();
    return array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    );
}
```

Is there a way to have the framework automagically guessing the customnum type on that field (in the form also?)

Comment: the doctrine CRUD actions will use the Form Type you described above, so there is no need to automagically detect it, if you have configured it in the FormBuilder. BUT you can create a form type guesser: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/dic_tags.html#form-type-guesser

Comment: Forms do it. But not the view of on indexAction. Naive testing shows: Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\DoctrineOrmGuesser is not used with views from indexAction(). ... Still searching a more elegant method than modifying the entities.